# Error while loading image 500 schedula task angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular 7 application that works fine and i can handle their error exceptions but i have an error that i couldn't understand it, while loading the image that doesn't exist in the database which i know it and handle the exception but another error shows in the console : 
[image]

Can anyone explain me the error and how solve it ?

This is the service.ts :

```
getFileByName(file: string): Observable<Blob> {
return this.http.get(this.baseUrl.getFileName.replace(':filename', file), { responseType: 'blob' })
  .catch(this.httpErrorHandler.handleError);
}
```

this is the comonent.ts :

```
this.fileUploadService.getFileByName('me.jpg').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.createImageFromBlob(data);
    this.isImageLoading = false;
    this.profilePicture = true;
  }, error => {
    this.isImageLoading = false;
    console.log('Could not get the profile picture: ' + error);
  }
);
```

Comment: HTTP status 500 basically means that there is some kind of error on a server side. You have to debug backend side to check what is actually happening on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use Request Interceptor instead of simple catch

**When your application grows, the amount of HTTP requests increases as well. Attaching a catch to every request is not exactly DRY.**

- This is how you do that:

  ```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';                       
  import{HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,HttpInterceptor,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse,} from '@angular/common/http';                                                        
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';                               
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';                                                                                                                                      
  @Injectable()                                                               
  export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {         
  constructor() {}                                                
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    // do error handling here
  }});   }  }
  ```

  see more in : "https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling"